# Query varchar column and pass character to character to a row in different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I trying to pass from a `varchar` column e.g. 12345, and I want to pass to another table like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I don't know how can get char by char and make a insert directly to another table. I'm using SQL Server database

Please can you give me examples how can I accomplish this.

What I have is just the query to select the column - but I don't know how can get char by char and insert to another table, and I need to validate if the char is example 0 don't insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select '' as chr, '12345' as rest, 0 as lev
      union all
      select left(rest, 1), stuff(rest, 1, 1, ''), lev + 1
      from cte
      where rest <> ''
     )
select chr
from cte
where lev > 0;
```

To insert into an existing table, you can simply add `insert` before the `select`:

```
with cte as (
      select '' as chr, '12345' as rest, 0 as lev
      union all
      select left(rest, 1), stuff(rest, 1, 1, ''), lev + 1
      from cte
      where rest <> ''
     )
insert into t (c)
    select chr
    from cte
    where lev > 0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c3470cdd0ff63e8ed34dc2e9e81cf095) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks so much, another question, if the value to  split comes from another select how can i do that or can i integrate the select statement in this query?

Comment: @IvanFontalvo . . . You can use that `select` for the first `select` in the recursive CTE.